# Cs-cart hook in backend order

Tags: php, hook, cs-cart

Which hook should I use in order to process all the information of an order in the cs cart backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
fn_set_hook('get_order_info', $order, $additional_data);
```

can be found in

```
app/functions/fn.cart.php
```

and make sure you are testing the enviroment

```
if(AREA=='A'){ ... }
```